# Bypassing OS Requirements in mpkg

Tags: macos, installation, osx-lion, installer

I have a mpkg file that i'm trying to install.

The installer quits after "writing files" with the error:

> The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to
>   fail...

Among a big process of Install.log in console i can see this line:

> Dec 22 14:45:56 MacBook-Pro installd[505]: ./postinstall:
>   arserver postinsall: Unsupported Operating system version! Exiting...

I'm on 10.7.6 and The file is supported to 10.6 and up, but it just wont install...
is there a way to ignore OS check while running this file?

[Source file](http://www.redmountainradio.com/arsuite/download.html)

EDIT:

Found the solution.

I edited the following exec file using Coda

> postinstall

inside the

> contents.pkg

And changed the lines from:

```
# ===========================================================================
# OS version dependent stuff 
# ===========================================================================
osv=`sw_vers -productVersion`
case $osv in
10.6*)
```

To:

```
 # ===========================================================================
    # OS version dependent stuff 
    # ===========================================================================
    osv=`sw_vers -productVersion`
    case $osv in
    10.7*)
```

And the installer ran and the app launched!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on 10.8, but the installer still copied all files to `/Applications/ARSuite/`. (You can see what files an installer is supposed to copy by pressing ⌘I.)

You could also extract `AudioRackSuite3.4.1.mpkg/Contents/Packages/contents.pkg/Contents/Archive.pax.gz` and move the files to the Applications folder manually.

Comment: I Followed your advice and the files copied indeed. i recopied them from inside just to be safe but it throws another error when opening the app. i updated the code above to the error log. thank you.

Comment: Found the workaround and edited the question. thank you m8.